# Android : How can I use method emitBubbles() in Question1 class

Tags: java, android, android-activity

I'm doing a quiz and I don't want to write in all of new Activities this method but I can't make it work. I was trying to make another java class to put there all methods but how do that
Hope u gonna help me guys

```
//Main class
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private Button button;
    BubbleEmitterView bubbleEmitter;
    Handler handler = new Handler();
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        emitBubbles();
        bubbleEmitter = findViewById(R.id.bubbleEmitter);

        button = findViewById(R.id.startButton);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startQuiz();
            }
        });


    }
    public void emitBubbles()
    {
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                //determine the size of the bubbles and the range
                int size = new Random().nextInt(81)+20;
                bubbleEmitter.emitBubble(size);
                emitBubbles();
            }
        },
                //determine the range for the bubbles to appear
                new Random().nextInt(301)+100);
    }


 //question class
    public class Question1 extends AppCompatActivity {

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_question1);

        }
    }
```

Comment: what are you trying to do? Please submit logcat trace if you have errors

Comment: Wat is your qyestion? Wat u want to do here? Use same method throughout the app ?

Comment: i just want to use bubbleEmitter() in my other activities. Its all about how i can use emitBubbles in Question1 class. I tried to do make MainActivity mainactivity = new MainActivity() and after mainactivity.bubbleEmit(); and its not working at all